# How can I streamline this code and reduce the time it takes to run?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, performance, convolution

I have a code which works perfectly, and I'm looking to make it more efficient.

```
t = -1:.001:1;
t_for_y = -50:.01:50;
x = zeros(size(t));
x(1001:end) = exp(-3 * t(1001:end));
h = zeros(size(t));
h(1001:end) = exp(-2 * t(1001:end)); % FIXED TYPO
for k = 1:length(t_for_y)  
    X(k)=trapz(t,x.*exp(-1i*t*t_for_y(k)));   
    H(k)=trapz(t,h.*exp(-1i*t*t_for_y(k)));  
end
Y = X.*H;
for k = 1:length(t)  
    y(k) = (1/(2*pi))*trapz(t_for_y,Y.*exp(1i*t(k)*t_for_y)); 
end
plot(t,real(y));grid on;
```

I'd like to only use one `for-loop` or no for loops is this possible?

Is there a way of using doing this faster?

Comment: I do not know how matlab optimizes the code. Assuming it doesn't do any optimization and only runs the code you've given then you could store any calculation you did into temp variable and keep using that instead of calculating every single time. `exp(-1i*t*t_for_y(k))` could be calculated and stored before the loop and reused instead of calculating every single time. `(1/(2*pi))` that could be pre calculated before the loop. But improving this, I don't think you would see much difference as reducing the loop but every single bit of improvements count.

Comment: For the part of the code: `exp(-1i*t*t_for_y(k))` to put this outside of the loop would it still increment with every section of the loop?

Comment: exp(-1i*t*t_for_y(k))  That part have to be inside the loop but calculated once and stored in variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `trapz` function can take a matrix as the second input (see `help trapz` for more info). This means that your first column can be replaced by the following:

```
t_i = 1i*t';
exp_t = bsxfun(@times,t_i,t_for_y); % Precompute for speed
xexp = bsxfun(@times,x',exp_t);
hexp = bsxfun(@times,h',exp_t);
% NOTE: As you've got it, X and H are identical - I assume this is a typo
X = trapz(t,xexp,1);
H = trapz(t,xexp,1);
```

Be aware that this will generate some fairly large matrices (~`2000 X 10000`), which can eat up your memory if you're not careful.

The second loop can be linearised in a similar manner:

```
% Using exp_t from the previous loop
yexp = bsxfun(@times,Y,exp_t);
% NOTE: As you've got it, X and H are identical - I assume this is a typo
y = trapz(t_for_y,xexp,2);
```

Again, this will use a lot of memory. You may find that you will save memory by using sparse matrices.

If memory is at a premium for you, then your original code is better (though you should preallocate `X`, `H` and `y` for a slight speed boost), as the time saved by linearising it is not really enough to justify the extra memory. If you've got memory aplenty, then this method is slightly faster.

Comment: If this will eat up memory then how does it make it more efficient?

Comment: It makes it more computationally efficient, by working on larger portions of the dataset simultaneously. A side-effect of this is that it will use more memory - in other words, it will be faster, but use more memory.